# SOPs with Terraform using Alias's

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, mozilla-sops

i have a working sops solution to encrypt files using 1 aws accounts (`aws_sops`) KMS and then deploy the secrets to another aws accounts secret manager (`aws_secrets`).

This is done via connecting to the `aws_sops` having the .sops.yaml file point at its kms and using an alias to deploy the secret.

while this works, it then saves the state of the `aws_secrets` workspace to the `aws_sops` statefile. Which means i cant deploy this solution to a terraform workspace that is already hosted in the `aws_secrets` account.

Is it possible to switch the solution to using an alias for `aws_sops` and connecting directly to `aws_secrets` account? I dont see how to tell sops to use the aws alias instead of the default.

### working solution (which i dont like):

```
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "development"
  profile = "development"
}

provider "aws" {}
provider "sops" {}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "xxx-statefile"
    encrypt = true
    key     = "pat/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

data "sops_file" "sops-secret" {
  source_file = "../secrets.json"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "pipeline" {
  provider                       = aws.development
  name                           = "service-accounts/pipeline/resource-access-pat"
  recovery_window_in_days        = 0
  force_overwrite_replica_secret = true
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "pipeline" {
  provider  = aws.development
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.pipeline.id
  secret_string = jsonencode(
    {
      "pat" : data.sops_file.sops-secret.data["token"]
  })
}
```

### failed solution 1

was to remove the provider alias from the secrets and put in the data call as thats the only time / place i can see sops getting called.

But that gets the error:

```
│ Error: Invalid data source
│ 
│   on ../data.tf line 1, in data "sops_file" "test":
│    1: data "sops_file" "test" {
│ 
│ The provider hashicorp/aws does not support data source "sops_file".
```

which makes sense as its just reading a local file.

### failed solution 2

it looks someone had a similar problem and raised a ticket: https://github.com/carlpett/terraform-provider-sops/issues/89

A possible solution was to add the role for the `aws_sops`

ive tried adding a role with admin permissions to kms etc like :

```
    "sops": {
        "kms": [
            {
                "arn": "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:xxx:key/xxx",
                "role": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/TerraformAccountAccessRole",
                "created_at": "2023-02-10T13:53:05Z",
                "enc": "xx==",
                "aws_profile": ""
            }
```

and tried adding the the aws_profile as well:

```
    "sops": {
        "kms": [
            {
                "arn": "arn:aws:kms:xxx:xxx:key/xxx",
                "role": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/TerraformAccountAccessRole",
                "created_at": "2023-02-10T13:53:05Z",
                "enc": "xx==",
                "aws_profile": "aws_sops"
            }
```

bit i get an error:

```
│ Error: Failed to get the data key required to decrypt the SOPS file.
│ 
│ Group 0: FAILED
│   arn:aws:kms:xxx:xxx:key/xxx: FAILED
│     - | Error creating AWS session: Failed to assume role
│       | "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/TerraformAccountAccessRole":
│       | AccessDenied: User:
│       | arn:aws:sts::089449186373:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_DevOps_xxx/xxx@xxx.com
│       | is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource:
│       | arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/TerraformAccountAccessRole
│       |       status code: 403, request id:
│       | d9327e8c-8ffc-4873-9279-112c1c8c7258
│ 
│ Recovery failed because no master key was able to decrypt the file. In
│ order for SOPS to recover the file, at least one key has to be successful,
│ but none were.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi resolved this via updating failed solution 2:

- Generate your sops secret file
- Update the json file adding in a role (That the caller of the terraform can ssume and the arn of the kms key
- update the versions.tf file

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.5"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 4.54"
    }
    sops = {
      source  = "carlpett/sops"
      version = "0.7.2"
    }
  }
}
```

This will tell sops when it tries to decypt your secret to assume into the role you specified using the KMS.

This worked for me, hope it helps